# Why do cookies on browser's DevTools never match the ones shown when clicking on the padlock?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics, devtools

For instance:

[image: padlock cookies]

vs only 11 on devtools:
[image]

Comment: My guess is that the information in the popup is from a specific moment in time (for instance, when you opened the page), and devtools is showing the current reality. But it's a guess.

Comment: Because the first one, despite how its called/titled, counts more than just the cookies, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/hejQo.png - local & session storage, as well as indexed database entries, are included. (Although you still can not see what the other ones besides the cookies actually contain, in this location, in Chrome at least.)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather, it is about viewing cookies in a web browser.  This question might be appropriate for [su] instead.